# batch download of pictures from flickr?

Tags: 11.10, flickr

Is there any command-line tool that can be run regularly to do a batch download of recent pictures from a Flickr account Photostream album in Ubuntu 11.10?

I configured `flickcurl`, but I can't find a command which can do something like download photos from last 7 days.